# Имеет ли смысл оборачивать абзацы в теги

Tags: html, seo

По прежнему в постах, а именно текст, абзацы.

По прежнему оборачиваю в тег `<p></p>`

В данный момент это все еще актуально, когда есть

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-break: break-word;
```

Которые собственно и сохраняют все отступы и переносы.

Возможно при парсинге поисковыми системами как то учитываются обзацы? Именно обернутые в теги `<p></p>`

??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это семантически абзац - заворачивайте в p, если это заголовок - заворачивайте в h1/h2/h.. Если картинка - в img (а не как один мессенджер - телеграм, который в вебверсии заворачивает картинку в тег `a` в стили, а сверху ещё div, что бы маленькие дети не могли сохранить картинку (хочется программистов Дурова отправить в школу, но ручек выдать палочки)).

Но зачем делать правильно (смешно звучит, не правда)?

Во первых, это красиво.

Во вторых, все браузеры точно понимают это и понимают это однозначно.

А в третьих, есть такая штука, как "читалки" для людей, которые плохо видят или не могут пользоваться полноценно клавиатурой/мышкой. И эти программы-читалки хорошо понимают стандартные теги, а вот все ручные разрывы - очень и очень плохо. У меня был случай, когда вебдизайнеру нужно было разместить подпись к полю ввода и визуально она была слева, но в коде - справа, но кучей стилей два элемента были прижаты в противоположные стороны. И читалки это читали совсем плохо. Переписал, страница стала весить меньше, выглядела также, а загружалась сильно быстрее (на странице было много таких "полей" ввода). А дизайнер просто был лентяем,  не хотел обменять два блока текста местами и надобавлял стилей.

А теперь к такой штуке как "seo". Многие думают, что дело в тегах. Нет. Или в бездумно напиханных "keyword'ах". Тоже не то. Сейчас для большинства поисковиков дело в контенте. Делайте хороший контент, чистую страницу (не перегруженную непонятно чем) и поисковики подтянуться. А остальные SEO рекомендации нужно выбросить. Они могут помочь на день-неделю, а потом все уходит в небытие.